# How to implement a generic C++ context parameter in Windows 10 Universal delegate?

Tags: delegates, win-universal-app, c++-cx

In rewriting the API for an existing C++ DLL into a Windows 10 Universal component, how to model generic 'context' parameters for the caller to define and use?   The original API was:

```
typedef void (*My_Callback) 
    (const int deviceHandle,
     void     *pContext);
```

I am trying to rewrite as

```
delegate void My_Callback(const int deviceHandle, ???? context);
```

Since the parameters must be passed across the Windows Runtime ABI, it cannot be a void *.  What would make sense in its place?

Comment: At the ABI level, delegates are COM objects with an Invoke method, so they already have context (namely the COM object's "this"). In other words: You don't need to have an explicit context. All delegates come with an implicit one.

Comment: As long as it is only ever used as "handle", in other words never dereferenced but just passed back to the api, then you can use [Platform::IntPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh755810.aspx).  Keep in mind that there is no reference counting, it isn't good enough to keep the owner object alive.  If you need that as well then you must declare an interface.